# How to use the S5 fingerprint scanner with full device encyption?

Tags: lock-screens, security

I am using the S5 and have decide to fully encrypt the device and the sd card. My biggest problem is that now the fingerprint is no a possible choice as a lockscreen security. Only password.

I believe changing lockscreen.password_type would solve the problem, but I have yet to find the value for fingerprint unlocking: (0 is for no locks, 65536 is for pattern lock, 131072 is for pin lock, etc)

Anyone can help?